# Magento 2 Frontend UI grid not display

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, customer-grid

I am working in magento 2.2 I want show the customer list in the frontend / vendor panel.

When accessing the url and check the response customer data is fetching in JSON format but customer grid is not display.

**JSON DATA :**

```
{"items":[{"id_field_name":"entity_id","entity_id":"1","name":"VeronicaVVV Costello","email":"roni_cost@example.com","group_id":["1"],"created_at":"2018-07-26 17:55:40","website_id":["1"],"confirmation":null,"created_in":"Default Store View","dob":"1973-12-15","gender":["2"],"taxvat":null,"lock_expires":null,"shipping_full":"6146 Honey Bluff Parkway Calder Michigan 49628-7978","billing_full":"6146 Honey Bluff Parkway Calder Michigan 49628-7978","billing_firstname":"Veronica","billing_lastname":"Costello","billing_telephone":"(555) 229-3326","billing_postcode":"49628-7978","billing_country_id":["US"],"billing_region":"Michigan","billing_street":"6146 Honey Bluff Parkway","billing_city":"Calder","billing_fax":null,"billing_vat_id":null,"billing_company":null,"orig_data":null,"actions":{"edit":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/magento\/mage22\/customer\/index\/edit\/id\/1\/","label":"Edit","hidden":false}}},{"id_field_name":"entity_id","entity_id":"2","name":"Arnav Hase","email":"arnavhase@gmail.com","group_id":["1"],"created_at":"2018-09-10 17:04:19","website_id":["1"],"confirmation":null,"created_in":"Default Store View","dob":null,"gender":null,"taxvat":null,"lock_expires":null,"shipping_full":"Anandnagar\nKalwa E Thane Maharashtra 400605","billing_full":"Anandnagar\nKalwa E Thane Maharashtra 400605","billing_firstname":"Arnav","billing_lastname":"Hase","billing_telephone":"9822334455","billing_postcode":"400605","billing_country_id":["IN"],"billing_region":"Maharashtra","billing_street":"Anandnagar\nKalwa E","billing_city":"Thane","billing_fax":null,"billing_vat_id":null,"billing_company":null,"orig_data":null,"actions":{"edit":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/magento\/mage22\/customer\/index\/edit\/id\/2\/","label":"Edit","hidden":false}}}],"totalRecords":2
```

**File : layout/hello_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="kh_customer_data"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**File : view/ui_component/kh_customer_data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <buttons>
                <button name="add">
                    <url path="*/*/new"/>
                    <class>primary</class>
                    <label translate="true">Add New Customer</label>
                </button>
            </buttons>
            <spinner>customer_columns</spinner>
            <deps>
                <dep>customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</dep>
            </deps>
        </settings>
        <dataSource name="customer_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
            <settings>
                <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
            </settings>
            <dataProvider class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider" name="customer_listing_data_source">
                <settings>
                    <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                    <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
                </settings>
            </dataProvider>
        </dataSource>
        <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
            <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        </listingToolbar>
        <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
            <settings>
                <editorConfig>
                    <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </param>
                    <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                    <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                    <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns.ids</param>
                </editorConfig>
                <childDefaults>
                    <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </param>
                </childDefaults>
            </settings>
            <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="10">
                <settings>
                    <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
                </settings>
            </selectionsColumn>
            <column name="entity_id" sortOrder="20">
                <settings>
                    <filter>textRange</filter>
                    <label translate="true">ID</label>
                    <sorting>asc</sorting>
                </settings>
            </column>
            <column name="name" sortOrder="30">
                <settings>
                    <filter>text</filter>
                    <label translate="true">Name</label>
                </settings>
            </column>
            <column name="email" sortOrder="40">
            </column>
            <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
                <settings>
                    <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
                </settings>
            </actionsColumn>
        </columns>
    </listing>
```

**File : etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customer_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: same problem to me